# Run two or more apps via powershell with one command

Tags: windows, powershell

this is my `user_profile.ps1' file with my alias list

```
# some data here

Set-alias idea 'C:\users\user\appdata\local\jetbrains\toolbox\apps\idea-c\ch-0\213.5744.223\bin\idea64.exe'
Set-Alias obsidian 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Obsidian\Obsidian.exe'
Set-Alias brave 'C:\Program Files\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\Application\brave.exe'

# and there
```

is possible to create "super alias" for this three (or more) apps to run it with one alias like when I type something like `superalias` and this run three (or more) apps. Maybe you know or other possibility instead of Set-Alias

P.S.
this doesn't work:

```
Set-Alias superalias 'C:\users\user\appdata\local\jetbrains\toolbox\apps\idea-c\ch-0\213.5744.223\bin\idea64.exe', 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Obsidian\Obsidian.exe', 'C:\Program Files\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\Application\brave.exe'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Aliases) in PowerShell can only refer to *one* other command name or path - it is simply an alternative (usually shorter) name for another command.

In order to invoke *multiple* commands you need a [*function*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions) (adjust the name as needed):

```
function superalias { 
  & 'C:\users\user\appdata\local\jetbrains\toolbox\apps\idea-c\ch-0\213.5744.223\bin\idea64.exe'
  & 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Obsidian\Obsidian.exe'
  & 'C:\Program Files\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\Application\brave.exe'
}
```

Note the need to use `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-), to invoke the external programs, which is a syntactic necessity because their paths are *quoted* (the same would apply if the paths contained variable names or expressions).

These external programs will launch sequentially, and any among them that are *console* applications will run *synchronously*, i.e. block further execution until they exit.

Comment: thank you so much. Short and convenient solution.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @SergeyMaksimov.